# how to truncate the string, or to extract a portion of the value from a string in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, substr

> hello , i have value 1284&kec=220107&prop=220000
>
> here i want to take the numbers in front **&**  the numbers in front
>   are not always three letters,  sometimes two letters and sometimes
>   also one, how to remove or delete values ​​after **&**
>
> ```
> example : 1284&kec=220107&prop=220000
> result value = 1284
>
> example : 11&kec=2332&prop=563454
> result value = 11
> ```
>
> can you give an example?

Comment: from a string? there's this thing called `strpos` and `substr` in php

Comment: You can use `chop()` function, answer has given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode()` to convert the `string` to an `array` and then get what you want. Like so -

```
$example = '1284&kec=220107&prop=220000';
$ex = explode("&kec", $example); // convert it to array where $kec is found
$value = $ex[0]; // output: 1284 // the first key will hold the value before $kec

$example2 ='11&kec=2332&prop=563454';
$ex = explode("&kec", $example2);
$value = $ex[0]; // output: 11
```